# Confused by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I came across this piece of jQuery and am wondering what it does. I'm new to jQuery but from what I can see I think it replaces an element with the id *reveal* to a link with the class *html5lightbox* and id *reveal*. What I don't understand is the meaning of `$( '#reveal' ).text()`

```
$( '#reveal' ).replaceWith( '<a class="html5lightbox" href="#" id="reveal">' + $( '#reveal' ).text() + '</a>');
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: *First* place to look when you don't know what a method does is [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text()` function simply gets the combined text contents of the element:

```
<div id="reveal">
  <div>Demonstration Box</div>
  <ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list <strong>item</strong> 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`$("#reveal").text()` would produce the following result:

```
Demonstration Box list item 1 list item 2
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

It get's the text from the current `#reveal`, and uses it in the new `#reveal`.

It would be the same as

```
var text   = $('#reveal').text();

var anchor = '<a class="html5lightbox" href="#" id="reveal">' + text + '</a>';

$( '#reveal' ).replaceWith( anchor );
```

Comment: bad example to show code that doesn't cache variables. i know you can do better :)

Comment: @japrescott - It makes absolutely no difference for this.

Comment: Negletable yes, but it does make a difference

Comment: @japrescott - Probably not, initializing and storing the variable probably takes up more resources than just running getElementById twice, and any way you twist and turn it, the difference would be something like 0.00000000003 milliseconds, so it really makes no difference, you don't *always* have to cache everything, and for this answer it's a lot more readable and verbose written like above.

Comment: I agree that the difference is negletable in THIS situation. But $("#id") is more than just a simple getElementById call and if someone gets accostumed to querying an element everytime they need it instead of caching it, they will have a tuff lesson to learn down the road. I just believe that we should do the best to help people by providing code that we would like to see in our own source.

Answer (score 1):

What it does is wrap what is inside the element with the id "reveal" with an anchor element ( a link). So the part you don't understand is it actually extracting the text from #reveal before it is replaced be `replaceWith`

Normally one would do such a thing with the [jquery function wrap](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

As a side note -> always cache your $("whatever") in a variable to reuse later. So your code should be;

```
var reveal=$( '#reveal' )
reveal.replaceWith( '<a class="html5lightbox" href="#" id="reveal">' + reveal.text() + '</a>');
```

or

```
reveal.wrap('<a class="html5lightbox" href="#"></a>');
```